# simple linq to sql has no supported translation to SQL

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

i have this in my BlogRepository

```
public IQueryable<Subnus.MVC.Data.Model.Post> GetPosts()
    {
        var query = from p in db.Posts
                    let categories = GetCategoriesByPostId(p.PostId)
                    let comments = GetCommentsByPostId(p.PostId)
                    select new Subnus.MVC.Data.Model.Post
                    {
                        Categories = new LazyList<Category>(categories),
                        Comments = new LazyList<Comment>(comments),
                        PostId = p.PostId,
                        Slug = p.Slug,
                        Title = p.Title,
                        CreatedBy = p.CreatedBy,
                        CreatedOn = p.CreatedOn,
                        Body = p.Body
                    };
        return query;
    }
```

and

```
public IQueryable<Subnus.MVC.Data.Model.Comment> GetCommentsByPostId(int postId)
    {
        var query = from c in db.Comments
                    where c.PostId == postId
                    select new Subnus.MVC.Data.Model.Comment
                    {
                        Body = c.Body,
                        EMail = c.EMail,
                        Date = c.CreatedOn,
                        WebSite = c.Website,
                        Name = c.Name
                    };

        return query;
    }

private IQueryable<Subnus.MVC.Data.Model.Category> GetCategoriesByPostId(int postId)
    {
        var query = from c in db.Categories
                    join pcm in db.Post_Category_Maps on c.CategoryId equals pcm.CategoryId
                    where pcm.PostId == postId
                    select new Subnus.MVC.Data.Model.Category
                    {
                        CategoryId = c.CategoryId,
                        Name = c.Name
                    };
        return query;
    }
```

and when i aplly this filter

```
namespace Subnus.MVC.Data
{
 public static class BlogFilters
 {
    public static IQueryable<Post> WherePublicIs(this IQueryable<Post> qry,bool state)
    {

        return from p in qry
               where p.IsPublic == state
               select p;
    }
 }
```

}

all this is in the same namespace if that help namespace Subnus.MVC.Data

when i try to do this

```
public class BlogService : IBlogService
{
...
    public IList<Post> GetPublicPosts()
    {
         return repository.GetPosts().WherePublicIs(true).ToList();
    }
 ...
 }
```

that is in the namespace Subnus.MVC.Service
it throws the error

```
Method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Subnus.MVC.Data.Model.Comment] GetCommentsByPostId(Int32)' has no supported translation to SQL.
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are calling `GetCommentsByPostId` within what is ultimately an expression tree. That tree, when composed in `BlogService.GetPublicPosts`, is converted to SQL.

During that conversion, it is just a method call, nothing more. Linq to Sql understands certain method calls, and yours is not one of them. Hence the error.

On the surface, this seems like it should work. You write reusable queries and compose them from other queries. However, what you are actually saying is: "during the processing of each row on the database server, call this method", which it obviously can't do. The fact that it takes an `IQueryable<T>` and returns an `IQueryable<T>` does not make it special.

Think about it this way: you are passing `postId` to `GetCategoriesByPostId`. You can't call that method until you have a `postId`, and you don't have one of those until you are on the server in the query.

You would probably need to define common `Expression<>` instances for the sub-queries and use those in the composition. I haven't thought about what this would look like but it's certainly doable.

**Edit:**

If you replace

```
let categories = GetCategoriesByPostId(p.PostId)
let comments = GetCommentsByPostId(p.PostId)
...
Categories = new LazyList<Category>(categories),
Comments = new LazyList<Comment>(comments),
```

with

```
Categories = new LazyList<Category>(GetCategoriesByPostId(p.PostId)),
Comments = new LazyList<Comment>(GetCommentsByPostId(p.PostId)),
```

the query will no longer throw an exception.

This is because `let` declares range variables, which are in scope for each row. They **must** be calculated on the server.

Projections, however, allow you to put arbitrary code in assignments, which is then executed while building results on the client. This means both methods will be called, each of which will issue its own query.

Comment: when i apply the filter the error still comes after the change

Comment: Try removing the WherePublicIsTrue call in GetPublicPosts (just to see).

Comment: Try doing .Where(post => post.Public)

Comment: As expected. It seems you can only use a custom method call as a top-level query or in the projection of a top-level query.

Comment: found the error look closely at the first code sample i don't define IsPublic in the new class i create when i do that the all works

Comment: Nice answer. Upvoted to push you over 3000. Use your new powers nicely :)

Comment: @BryanWatts Is it possible to get rid of such errors by adding the desired custom function `GetCommentsByPostId` in sql server itself by using sql server clr integration feature?  That way sql server engine will be able to detect it as a function. One thing is sure that you can't compile such a linq query in C# until you have defined a dummy function with same name even after the clr integration is in place. Please suggest.

Comment: @RBT: It sounds plausible but I haven't attempted it. I know there is a way to declare static methods in C# code that correspond to server functions - you may look into that.