# Problem with LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

The following works fine:

```
                    (from e in db.EnquiryAreas
                            from w in db.WorkTypes
                            where
                            w.HumanId != null &&
                            w.SeoPriority > 0 &&
                            e.HumanId != null &&
                            e.SeoPriority > 0 &&
                            db.Enquiries.Where(f => 
                                f.WhereId == e.Id && 
                                f.WhatId == w.Id && 
                                f.EnquiryPublished != null && 
                                f.StatusId != EnquiryMethods.STATUS_INACTIVE &&
                                f.StatusId != EnquiryMethods.STATUS_REMOVED &&
                                f.StatusId != EnquiryMethods.STATUS_REJECTED &&
                                f.StatusId != EnquiryMethods.STATUS_ATTEND
                            ).Any()
                            select
                            new
                            {
                                EnquiryArea = e,
                                WorkType = w
                            });
```

But:

```
               (from e in db.EnquiryAreas
                            from w in db.WorkTypes
                            where
                            w.HumanId != null &&
                            w.SeoPriority > 0 &&
                            e.HumanId != null &&
                            e.SeoPriority > 0 &&
                            EnquiryMethods.BlockOnSite(db.Enquiries.Where(f => f.WhereId == e.Id && f.WhatId == w.Id)).Any()
                            select
                            new
                            {
                                EnquiryArea = e,
                                WorkType = w
                            });
```

+

```
   public static IQueryable<Enquiry> BlockOnSite(IQueryable<Enquiry> linq)
    {
        return linq.Where(e => 
            e.EnquiryPublished != null && 
            e.StatusId != STATUS_INACTIVE &&
            e.StatusId != STATUS_REMOVED &&
            e.StatusId != STATUS_REJECTED &&
            e.StatusId != STATUS_ATTEND
        );
    }
```

I get the following error:

> base {System.SystemException}: {"Method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[X.Enquiry] 
>   BlockOnSite(System.Linq.IQueryable`1[X.Enquiry])' has no supported translation to SQL."}

Comment: Did you google the error message? It's pretty self descriptive.

Comment: Check out this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332670/simple-linq-to-sql-has-no-supported-translation-to-sql . Bruno forgot to paste this when copying his answer.

Comment: I understand the error message, but not how I can rewrite this so that it works with BlockOnSite type of function.

Comment: @Niels : you can't. Linq to SQL will never be able to translate your BlockOnSite method call to SQL, because it is not a supported method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq to Sql only translates certain method calls to SQL, and yours (`BlockOnSite`) is not one of them. Hence the error. The fact that your method takes an `IQueryable<T>` and returns an `IQueryable<T>` doesn't make it special.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved it using:

```
        IQueryable<Enquiry> visibleOnSite = EnquiryMethods.VisibleOnSite(db.Enquiries);

        var combinations = (from e in db.EnquiryAreas
                            from w in db.WorkTypes
                            where
                            w.HumanId != null &&
                            w.SeoPriority > 0 &&
                            e.HumanId != null &&
                            e.SeoPriority > 0 &&
                            visibleOnSite.Where(f => f.WhereId == e.Id && f.WhatId == w.Id).Any()
                            select
                            new
                            {
                                EnquiryArea = e,
                                WorkType = w
                            });
```