# Linq function like .Net string.CompareOrdinal

Tags: c#, string, linq, entity-framework-4.1, comparison

I need to compare strings using the `string.CompareOrdinal(...)` inside a linq query.

```
string max;
string min;

var res = db.Table
            .Where(c => string.CompareOrdinal(c.Id,  min) >= 0)
            .Where(c => string.CompareOrdinal(c.Id,  max) <= 0)
            .ToList();
```

The code throws a exception:

> LINQ ti Entities does not recongnize the method 'Int32
>   CompareOrdinal(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method
>   cannot be translated into a store expression.

There are a lot of data in the table, so I really need the `where` clause.

Is there a way around this?

**Update**

I'm *not* trying to deside if two strings are equal - case sensitive or not.

I'm trying to deside whether a string is within a *range*.
So the quistion is

- Is there a way to do that - so that is works with L2E?

Obviously, I cannot use the `string.CompareOrdinal`

Comment: have you tried something similar.. I mean.. this one may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332670/simple-linq-to-sql-has-no-supported-translation-to-sql

Comment: I think that code should give a compile error "No overload for method 'CompareOrdinal' takes 1 arguments"

Comment: possible duplicate of [linq to entities case sensitive comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843060/linq-to-entities-case-sensitive-comparison)

Comment: FYI, here is a link that specified all the non-compatible method of String http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882672(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A colleague of mine found a workaround using [`string.Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of [`string.CompareOrdinal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/af26w0wa%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
string min = "a";
string max = "z";

 var res = db.Table
         .Where(c => string.Compare(c.Id, min, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
         .Where(c => string.Compare(c.Id, max, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) <= 0)
         .ToList();
```

this is the generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Table] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] >= 'a') AND ([Extent1].[Id] <= 'z')
```

Answer (score 0):

If Id is a string, this solution works, so it looks like Id is an int. Int cannot be compared to a string. Change Id to a string or min/max to an int to make it work (and use a simple < and > between the int values).

By the way: it would save 1 iteration to check for min and max in 1 where function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I was using Linq To Objects (L2O) the above statement *would work*. However in L2E the provider cannot translate the statement into any SQL.
L2E uses deffered loading. By the time the query hits the database, the two `Where` clauses have been combined.