# The LINQ expression '(str1.CompareTo(str2) < 0)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am trying to make an alphabetical comparison in LINQ but the expression cannot be compiled in SQL.

Any hint?

The suggested answer does not work. I get:

```
The LINQ expression '(Compare([f].str1, str2, Ordinal) < 0)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
```

Update: I am using the PredicateBuilder found in http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: if str are strings just write (str1 < str2)

Comment: @Seb: How would you expect that to even compile? There's no `<(string, string)` operator.

Comment: @Seb you can't test inequalities on string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq function like .Net string.CompareOrdinal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784340/linq-function-like-net-string-compareordinal)

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `string.Compare(...)`

```
.Where(e => string.Compare(str1, str2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0)
```

Comment: Actually the third argument doesn't matter, so `string.Compare(str1, str2)` is sufficient.

Comment: It still does not like it:

The LINQ expression '(Compare([f].str1, str2, Ordinal) < 0)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

Comment: if you want more help you will need to include sample code such as the method body giving you problems.  The issue seems to be in the way you are constructing your query.

Comment: I am using this class to construct my query: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx